# OpenCL kernel not using full GPU power

Tags: opencl, gpu, nvidia

I have an OpenCL kernel which makes some calculations with given matrices. This kernel receives matrices that are about 1280x720 size. It works perfect and outputs the results that I want. The only con with it is that it only uses about a 9%-10% processing power of my NVIDIA dedicated graphics card. This means I could improve the processing times about 10 times, but I haven't figured out how to do it. I think I could use local memory instead of global memory, but I don't know how to do that. Is there something more I could do to use my total GPU processing power or it is not possible?

This is the kernel code (removing the if-else statement does not improve anything. I've already tried it):

```
__kernel void matrix_dot_vector(const unsigned int size, const unsigned int width, const unsigned int height, __global const float4 *frame1, __global const float4 *frame2, __global const float2 *flow, __global float4 *result)
{
    int x = get_global_id(1);
    int y = get_global_id(0);

    if(flow[x + size * y].x >= 1 || 
       flow[x + size * y].y >= 1 || 
       flow[x + size * y].x <= -1 || 
       flow[x + size * y].y <= -1)
    {
        // For Windows
        int x_coord_0 = min((int) (x + 0.5f * flow[x + size * y].x), (int)(width - 1));
        int y_coord_0 = min((int) (y + 0.5f * flow[x + size * y].y), (int)(height - 1));
        int x_coord_1 = min((int) (x - 0.5f * flow[x + size * y].x), (int)(width - 1));
        int y_coord_1 = min((int) (y - 0.5f * flow[x + size * y].y), (int)(height - 1));

        result[x + size * y] = 0.5f * frame1[x_coord_0 + size * y_coord_0] + 0.5f * frame2[x_coord_1 + size * y_coord_1];
    }
    else
    {
        result[x + size * y] = frame1[x + size * y];
    }
}
```

Kind regards to anyone answering this question. Thanks!

Comment: How did you calculate that percentage? Is it just based on compute power? Your kernel looks like it is I/O-bound, not compute-bound.

Comment: Maybe you should look at starting configuration i.e. "Local group size" should be multiple of 32(NVIDIA cards).

Comment: @Dithermaster I calculated that using the Windows 10 task manager, which, after Fall Creators Update shows the GPU usage percentage.

Comment: Most vendors provide an OpenCL "Best Practise" or "Optimization Guide" that describes the device- and SDK-specific stuff necessary to make the code perform. These are a good starting point.